# What kind of hard drive connector is this?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, connector

This is a laptop hard drive. It's from a 2001 model Compaq Armada M700. The label on th disk says it's a Toshiba, MK3017GAP hdd2159 (although searching for that throws up a drive with a standard IDE connector.

[image: My hard drive connector]

What kind of connector is it? I need to get a USB converter for it. For context, it is not a normal sata or pata connector:
[image]

So what is it?

Comment: Looks like a proprietary adapter. Remove the screws and try to remove it.

Comment: This looks like an old compaq connector. Haven't seen it in years so may be mistaken. A connector that was only compatible with their products. Is it possible to pull of the black plastic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From ["Armada M700 Hard Drive Installation Guide"](http://www.bixnet.com/arm7ser1.html):

> 6. Lift the bezel up 90 degrees to create a handle. Pull the hard drive out of the hard drive bay.
> 7. Remove the 4 black screws at each corner and lift off the black tray.
> 8. Gently *remove the silver bracket and **connector***.
> 9. **Place connector** on new hard drive.

So there's probably an adapter that converts PATA on the drive to that proprietary connector.

Daniel B (in comments) found a picture of that adapter off the drive:

[image]

So you should be able to pull it off the drive, and then use any PATA->USB adapter you'd like.

Comment: I found a different image which is exactly what’s visible, on [this page](http://www.pchub.com/uph/laptop/38-36980-441/Compaq-Armada-M700-HDD-Caddy-Adapter.html). Either way, the drive is still in its caddy. That needs to be removed.

Comment: @DanielB I think that image you linked is of the internal piece that goes from the PATA connector on the motherboard to the chassis (where the drive, in the caddy, would be plugged into)...?

Comment: No, it runs inside the caddy. In the OP’s picture, we’re looking at the long side of the drive. The connector is upside down in one of the pictures.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I thought we were looking a the laptop itself. :)

Comment: Thanks, this was right, I didn't realise it was a caddy. Unscrewed it and got at the hdd